# Function to merge 2 lists of numbers and order them from least to greatest?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, loops

I have to create a function that will take 2 input streams and an output stream. The function is supposed to read a list of integers from 2 separate files, merge that list, order the numbers from least to greatest, then output this consolidated and ordered list onto a new file.

Here's the code for the function:

```
void merge(ifstream& inStream1, ifstream& inStream2, ofstream& outStream)
{
    int arr[100], i = 0;

    while(!inStream1.eof())
    {
        inStream1>>arr[i++];
    }

    while(!inStream2.eof())
    {
        inStream2>>arr[i++];
    }

    int indexOfNextSmallest;
    for (int index = 0; index < i - 1; index++)
    {
        indexOfNextSmallest = indexOfSmallest(arr, index, i);
        swapValues(arr[index], arr[indexOfNextSmallest]);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < i; index++)
    {
        outStream<<arr[index]<<endl;
    }
}

int indexOfSmallest(const int arr[], int startIndex, int i)
{
    int min = arr[startIndex], indexOfMin = startIndex;

    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < i; index++)
    {
        min = arr[index];
        indexOfMin = index;
    }
    return indexOfMin;
}

void swapValues(int& v1, int& v2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = temp;
}
```

Here's a sample input output:

file 1 has these numbers:

```
4
5
8
11
18
28
```

file 2 has these numbers:

```
87
234
11
8
9
45
23
```

This outputs to the new file:

```
23
4
5
8
11
18
28
1988923808
87
234
11
8
9
45
```

I'm totally lost. Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: and that's not how Stack Overflow works. What part are you lost in? Explain a bit more.

Comment: My advice is to use std::set. It addresses exactly the kind of problem you are facing!

Comment: @therainmaker I gave a sample input and output. How can I correct the output? It reads all the numbers in so the input is working but the output part isn't functioning, there's a random number there and the ordering is not working. This is pretty clear from what I've posted. What other info can I give?

Comment: `indexOfSmallest` is wrong, it always returns `i`. `if` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int arr[100]
```

Why? Do you know that there won't be more than 100 elements in both files, combined? Probably not, right?

So you better use a data structure that can dynamically adapt it's size, like a `std::vector`. But, since you also seem to want to remove duplicates, a `std::set` is the better choice. This gives you another bonus: The elements of a `std::set` are sorted.

This way, your problem reduces to:

```
void merge(std::istream & in1, std::istream & in2, std::ostream & out) {
 // The set is used to store the elements from both files.
 // Since it also sorts them, no explicit sorting is needed.
 // Duplicates will be removed, if that's not what you want, use a multiset
 std::set<int> storage;
 // The istream_iterator applies operator>> to the whole file, effectively
 // reading the whole file contents.
 storage.insert(
   std::istream_iterator<int>(in1),
   std::istream_iterator<int>());
 storage.insert(
   std::istream_iterator<int>(in2),
   std::istream_iterator<int>());
 // We copy each element of the set (they're in sorted order) into
 // the output. Using the ostream_iterator, it's like writting
 // for (auto element : storage) { out << element << " "; }
 std::copy(
   std::begin(storage), std::end(storage),
   std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, " ")); // if you want seperate lines use "\n"
}
```

With your input and this code I get:

```
4 5 8 9 11 18 23 28 45 87 234
```

**Use** what the standard library provides you!

---

Concerning your code:

```
int indexOfSmallest(const int arr[], int startIndex, int i)
{
    int min = arr[startIndex], indexOfMin = startIndex;

    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < i; index++)
    {
        min = arr[index]; /* HERE */
        indexOfMin = index;
    }
    return indexOfMin;
}
```

You don't look, whether the current element (at `index`) is actually smaller than the current minimum!

```
// inside that loop
if (arr[index] < min) {
 min = arr[index];
 indexOfMin = index;
}
```

(Of course, there's also [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element).)

Oh, and:

```
void merge(ifstream & //...
```

Don't hard code requirements that you do not have. You don't need *file* streams here, just streams, so `istream` and `ostream` are better choices.

And also:

```
while(!inStream1.eof())
{
    inStream1>>arr[i++];
}
```

Consider the file containing a text string `hello`. Then your stream will fail, but you continue to read input. Better test directly on the input operation:

```
while (inStream1 >> arr[i++]);
```

Comment: That was great. Really broke it down for me. The reason why I've put in file streams and not accounted for text strings etc. is because my textbook question gives these restrictions.